# Slice image and save each slice

Tags: powershell, image-processing, slice

I need to load an image from a file such as bmp and jpg and then slice it using coordinates and then save those slices.  I have had a look around and found the following code and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of amending this code to do what I want

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$destRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 8, 0, 8, 8
$srcRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 0, 8, 8, 8
$src=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\tmp\dolphin.jpg")
$bmp=new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap 64,64
$graphics=[System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
$units = [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel
$graphics.DrawImage($src, $destRect, $srcRect, $units)
$graphics.Dispose()
$bmp.Save("C:\tmp\output.png")
```

Comment: This is probably not what you need, but with Python it can be done easily :)